# python, google cloud platform: unable to overwite a file from google bucket: CRC32 does not match

Tags: google-cloud-platform, yaml, md5, crc32

I am using python3 client to connect to google buckets and trying to the following

- download 'my_rules_file.yaml'
- modify the yaml file
- overwrite the file

Here is the code that i used

```
from google.cloud import storage
import yaml

client = storage.Client()
bucket = client.get_bucket('bucket_name')
blob = bucket.blob('my_rules_file.yaml')
yaml_file = blob.download_as_string()

doc = yaml.load(yaml_file, Loader=yaml.FullLoader)
doc['email'].clear()
doc['email'].extend(["test@gmail.com"])
yaml_file = yaml.dump(doc)

blob.upload_from_string(yaml_file, content_type="application/octet-stream")
```

This is the error I get from the last line for upload

```
BadRequest: 400 POST https://storage.googleapis.com/upload/storage/v1/b/fc-sandbox-datastore/o?uploadType=multipart: {
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Provided CRC32C \"YXQoSg==\" doesn't match calculated CRC32C \"EyDHsA==\".",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Provided CRC32C \"YXQoSg==\" doesn't match calculated CRC32C \"EyDHsA==\".",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "invalid"
      },
      {
        "message": "Provided MD5 hash \"G/rQwQii9moEvc3ZDqW2qQ==\" doesn't match calculated MD5 hash \"GqyZzuvv6yE57q1bLg8HAg==\".",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "invalid"
      }
    ]
  }
}
: ('Request failed with status code', 400, 'Expected one of', <HTTPStatus.OK: 200>)
```

why is this happening. This seems to happen only for ".yaml files".

Comment: Hey, the similar issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63823624/google-cloud-storage-mismatch-in-crc32c-md5-while-upload-string-to-gcs

Answer (score 3):

The reason for your error is because you are trying to use the same blob object for both downloading and uploading this will not work you need two separate instances... You can find some good examples here [Python google.cloud.storage.Blob() Examples](https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/104465/google.cloud.storage.Blob)

You should use a seperate blob instance to handle the upload you are trying with only one...

```
.....
blob = bucket.blob('my_rules_file.yaml')
yaml_file = blob.download_as_string()
.....
```

the second instance is needed here

```
....
blob.upload_from_string(yaml_file, content_type="application/octet-stream")
...
```